# SQL ~ How to sort alphabetically WHEN value is same

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have table like this ordered in DESC order by value "key":

```
name | key
Bman  9.5
Cman  9.5
Aman  9.5
Ara   9.3
```

I want to sort it alphabetically when the key value is same
So I want it to be like this:

```
name | key
Aman  9.5
Bman  9.5
Cman  9.5
Ara   9.3
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use two `order by` keys:

```
order by key desc, name
```

Comment: wow lol i did something similar but i put the name value inside the ORDER BY and it gave me unrelated output , this my first project using SQL Thank you! i will set this as answer after the timer finishes